# Supermicro IPMI SSL

Tags: ssl, ipmi, supermicro

I have a Supermicro X9SCA-F serverboard and I'm trying to secure Super Doctor III IPMI by using SSL.  I generated my own certs (done this many times before), uploaded via the web interface, then it said it needed to restart & I clicked OK, but it never came back up.  Right now it's not listening on port 80 or 443 it seems.  I also power cycled the box a few times (shutting down & physically removing power for 5 mins), but that didn't seem to help either.  Before I did this, it was working fine, so I'm not sure what may have happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up resetting the IPMI interface by downloading the IPMI tools for Linux from Supermicro's website, making a bootable linux USB drive & copying the tools over to them, booting to it, & issuing `./ipmicfg-linux.x86.static -fd`.  This has to be done from the server/workstation directly.

Comment: Another trick if using the command line firmware update from a MS command prompt is to use the -C option which also resets it to factory. Just reapply the same version.